# What do I need to have for 12 hours stopover with a small trip to Kiev city?

Tags: airports, stopovers, ukraine, russian-citizens

I'm planning to buy tickets with a 12-hour stop in Boryspil International Airport, Ukraine during which I want to visit Kiev. I have Russian foreigner passport and Finnish working permit. Do I need anything else to successfully leave the transit area and get back later?

Comment: The website of the Ukrainian embassy in Russia should tell you what the visa requirements are.

Comment: Are you male or female? The question may sound odd, but unless the ban has been recently lifted, male Russian citizens between the age of 16 and 60 have been banned from entering Ukraine since November or December 2018.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold for now.